# What is the most upvoted question on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, up-votes

I was wondering what the most upvoted question on stackoverflow is. And are there any official lists for me to look through for the most upvoted questions and/or answears?

Comment: [Sort the question list by votes](http://i.imgur.com/TPMv5.png) - BAMM you got it :P

Comment: Oh, I hoped somebody would say "make it this one" like the guy who asked about the most downvoted :(

Comment: You were trying to get upvotes by asking what question had the most upvotes?

Comment: @Lix I think, had Magakahn succeeded, the world would have imploded. Or exploded. Or anti-ploded. Or something.

Comment: Haha, its always fun to read questions from @Magakahn. Always ask questions similar too this to get upvotes ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Click on the question tab and then sort the list by votes -

[image]

Comment: This answer has not just one, but *two* hand-drawn circles, *plus* a double-arrow line!

Comment: And its a `CW` so feel free... ;)

Comment: Note that this doesn't show deleted questions, like the database query I posted does. Not sure if that matters to the OP.

Comment: @ric - deleted questions (until deemed otherwise) don't and shouldn't matter to the general public of users. They were deemed not worthy (in their current form) for the community.  10+Kers on the other hand... well... I don't have to tell you :P

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/72633) is a database query you can use to check top questions.

> SELECT Score, Title from Posts Where Score > 1000 AND PostTypeId = 1 ORDER BY Score DESC